# Custom Conditions for Control Options in Azure Devops piepline for powershell variable

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want a task to be conditional on a variable set in another task in Azure Devops, but the variable is set in powershell.

I create the variable like this (first step)

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SPNinSQL;]$false"
```

I output the variable in the second step

```
Write-Host $(SPNinSQL)
```

The third step i want it to be conditional and this is my condition

```
and(succeeded(), eq($env:SPNinSQL, false))
```

any idea on how i need to write my variable for the condition to work correctly.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally execute a task within your pipeline with an Powershell variable this condition will work correctly.

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['SPNinSQL'], 'False'))
```

SPNinSQL is the powershell variable in this example.